# REST API how to define if custom object has tab or not in salesforce

Tags: rest-api, rest

Is it possible to define if custom object has tab or not in salesforce?

thx in advance

Comment: Are you sure that "define" is the correct word to use here? Did you perhaps mean "detect" or "determine"? "define" in this context makes me think that you want to either create or destroy a tab for an object, which sounds like the realm of the metadata api rather than the rest api. Also, what research have you done so far? This sounds like a question that should be able to be answered by looking through the SFDC documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a GET request at

```
/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/YourObjectName/listviews
```

it will return you a JSON like this:

```
{
  "done" : true,
  "listviews" : [ ],
  "nextRecordsUrl" : null,
  "size" : 0,
  "sobjectType" : "Your_Object__c"
}
```

if the size is 0, there is no tab for this sObject.